# Libjpeg static and dynamic libraries are different?

Tags: jpeg, static-libraries, decoder, dynamic-library

For decoding jpeg images I used libjpeg library which I built from source available in the link http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8b.tar.gz

But, somehow decode results from static and dynamic libjpeg libraries seems to be different which I think shouldn't be the case.

Did anyone face the same problem ? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much different? Did you build the libraries with the same options?

Comment: I havent changed anything in the configure file. So, is there any particular options that we need to set while creating static library?

Comment: And i'm seeing maximum of 3 pixel differences in the results between static and dynamic library

Comment: If they are +/-1 differences, something is different in the settings somehow.

Comment: Oh .. okay. I did not change anything in the config file hoping that the default source code will have the setup.